# Pinging Cortex-M7

Tags: c, stm32, ethernet, lwip, stm32h7

I am currently making my first dual-core microcontroller project. I want to use the STM32H745BI. So I bought the STM32H745I-DISCO to develop my project on. One part of the project is making a webinterface to communicate with the machine. So I started with trying to ping my device. I could not get it to work so I copied the code of this from [Controllers Tech video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8r8w6mgSn1A&t=920s&ab_channel=ControllersTech).

```c
<main.c>
/* GV from user code 0*/
extern struct netif gnetif;

int main(void)
{
  // all init stuff that is generated
  while(1)
  {
    ethernetif_input(&gnetif);

    sys_check_timeouts();
  }
}
```

```
<STM32H745XIHX_FLASH.ld>
SECTIONS
{
  // All generated stuff in sections

  .lwip_sec   (NOLOAD) :
    {
      . = ABSOLUTE(0x30000000);
      *(.RxDecripSection)
    
      . = ABSOLUTE(0x30000080);
      *(.TxDecripSection)
    
      . = ABSOLUTE(0x30000200);
      *(.RxArraySection)
    } >RAM_D2
    .ARM.attributes 0 : { *(.ARM.attributes) }
}
```

Here are the picture's of the IOC file:

- [cortex_m7](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RIe33.png)
- [Ethernet picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0wYCF.png) [Ethernet picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vKxSF.png)
- [LWIP picture 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dRAZ0.png) [LWIP picture 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MGyhu.png)

Result: [Pinging](https://i.stack.imgur.com/46OSv.png)

I am not sure what the problem is. It also could just be a typo but I am not sure. [Here](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1OvneWFZ2wnOUtd6TStxFcVqTvytwNTX9?usp=sharing) is the link to google drive link for the project. I am using STM32CubeIde Version 1.8.0.

Answer (score -1):

The problem was the gateway. Check your own gateway if it does not work.

Comment: This answer says very little, a gateway is not always required to run a network, so what to check?